# How to recover from curl: (56) Send failure: Connection was reset?

Tags: curl

I am using curl on Windows to download large files. However, the network connection is at times reset, and so I want to restart the download but unsure what parameters I should use.

I have tried

> curl.exe --connect-timeout 240 --keepalive-time 240
> --verbose --retry 50 --retry-max-time 0 --compressed -o "c:\largefile.bin" -C - https://example.org/largefile.bin

but the `--retry` doesn't work.

When connection is reset for some reason the `--verbose` shows the following:

```
* ...
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with example.org port 443
* Send failure: Connection was reset
* schannel: failed to send close msg: Failed sending data to the peer (bytes written: -1)
curl: (56) Send failure: Connection was reset
```

How do I get curl to retry on the `curl: (56) Send failure: Connection was reset`?

Comment: Note that you are not "recovering", you are starting a new transfer at the point where the old transfer was interrupted. `-C -` is sufficent for that (if the peer server supports partial transfers), the rest is fine tuning that depends on the exact circumstances, and need to be found out by trial and error (if you need it at all).

Comment: Using `-C -` will only resume from where I left _once I issue_ the command again. If the connection breaks, network cable is pulled, power goes, `-C -` will not restart the download (recover). So `-C -` does not solve my problem.

Comment: Yes. And the various "retries" will determine if and how long curl does this automatically, before it gives up. So it all depends on what you want to do: automatically retry until you get the file, even if it needs 100.000 retries? Give up on your end first if the TCP stream looks dead? Etc. etc. And all this depends on the circumstances. And also, please do this first by issuing the command again, manually, to verify if the server actually supports partial transfers. Because if it doesn't, you'll start again at the beginning. And with a bad network you may never complete.

Comment: The server supports partial transfers. If the connection is lost at client where curl command is issued, `-C -` unfortunately does not automatically restart the connection. I have to issue the command again, manually (which is exactly what I want to be automatically). `--retry 50`also does not solve the problem either.

Comment: Ah, you are trying to get curl to **retry** on this particular error, and it **doesn't** with the options you tried. Sorry, that was not clear from the question. Either use `--retry-all-errors` (since curl 7.71.0), though I have not tried this with this particular error, so it may work or not, or use `wget -c`, where this works without extra options. Also, please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: `--retry-all-errors` has done the magic. Please submit an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl` by default does not retry on all errors, even with `--retry`.

So either use `--retry-all-errors` (since curl 7.71.0), or use `wget -c`, where this works without extra options.

Answer (score 1):

Because `--retry-all-errors` wasn't supported by our version of `curl` on a linux-based container (error message: `curl: option --retry-all-errors: is unknown`), we ended up using a `while` loop:

```sh
while ! curl -s -f -o largefile.bin https://example.org/largefile.bin
do echo "will retry in 2 seconds"; sleep 2; done
```